# Object variable or With block variable not set, Selecting index of my.settings ArrayList

Tags: vb.net, arraylist, indexing

i am trying to specify the index of an ArrayList Saved in My.Settings in the following Manner

```
My.Settings("Sup" & Selectedsupplier).Item(0) = Convert.ToDouble(Margin1TextBox.Text)
```

i am having a problem specifying the index and the above code gives the following Error "Object variable or With block variable not set."

i've multiple ArrayLists in My.Settings, named Sup1, Sup2 up to Sup20 now i want to be able to specify the number in the name as variable  and i want to be able to select some index from the selected ArrayList.

is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not problem with your example. The reason you have this error is the ArrayList settings object are not set. The first time your app is run, the UserSetting need to be initializes by assigning a new instance to your ArrayList settings

This a function that check the setting and then assign the value.

```
Private Sub SetSettingValue(ByVal settingName As String, ByVal itemIndex As Integer, ByVal value As Double)
    Dim setting As ArrayList

    If (My.Settings(settingName) Is Nothing) Then
        My.Settings(settingName) = New ArrayList
    End If

    setting = CType(My.Settings(settingName), ArrayList)

    If (itemIndex >= setting.Count) Then
        Do
            setting.Add(Nothing)

        Loop While (itemIndex >= setting.Count)
    End If

    setting(itemIndex) = value
End Sub
```